# Whether `const` will be discarded or not when deducing from universal reference?

Tags: c++, templates, forwarding-reference

I found this question when learning the universal(forwarding) reference. The code is as follows.

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout

#include <type_traits>

template <class T> // deductions among universal reference
void fun(T &&b)    // fold reference, maintain const
{
    std::cout << b << " ";
    std::cout << std::is_const<T>::value << " ";
    std::cout << std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value << " ";
    std::cout << std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    fun(a);            // lvalue: T=int&
    fun(std::move(a)); // rvalue: T=int

    const int ca = 1;
    fun(ca);            // const_lvalue: T=int& （why no const?）
    fun(std::move(ca)); // const_rvalue: T=const int

    int &la = a;
    fun(la); // lvalue_ref: T=int&

    int &&ra = 1;
    fun(ra);                             // rvalue_ref: T=int& (r_ref is an l_val)
    fun(std::forward<decltype(ra)>(ra)); // rvalue_ref + perfect forwarding T=int

    const int &cla = a;
    fun(cla); // const_lvalue_ref: T=int& (no const?)

    const int &&cra = 1;
    fun(cra); // const_rvalue_ref: T=int& (no const?)

    return 0;
}
```

The results are as follows. As can be seen, when the input argument is `lvalue`, `const` is **discarded** when parsing the type of `T`. However, when it is `r_value`, `const` is **maintained**.

```
1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0  <-const is discarded   //const_lvalue: T=int&
1 1 0 0  <-const is maintained  //const_rvalue: T=const int
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0  <-const is discarded  //const_lvalue_ref: T=int&
1 0 1 0  <-const is discarded  //const_rvalue_ref: T=int&
```

Moreover, when I tried to use [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/a54ee863) to run this code, it generates `4` **template specializations**.

```
/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:18 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
void fun<int &>(int & b)
{

}
#endif

/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:19 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
void fun<int>(int && b)
{

}
#endif

/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:22 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
void fun<const int &>(const int & b)
{

}
#endif


/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:23 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
void fun<const int>(const int && b)
{

}
#endif
```

As can be seen from the result, `const` is **maintained** after the parsing process in cppinsights.

Can someone tell me why the results from my code and cppinsights are different? (Why `l_value` in my code is deduced to `T&` rather than `const T&`?)

In other words, what is the correct answer for the problem: Whether `const` will be discarded or not when deducing from `universal reference`?

Comment: `const int &` is a reference to const int. It's not const by itself, references never are (that would be `int &const`, which isn't a thing). Apply `std::remove_reference_t`.

Comment: q.v. is_const and the part about references: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const

Comment: Thanks for your reference link. I found there's a note saying that: If `T` is a `reference type` then `is_const<T>::value` is always `false`. The proper way to check a potentially-reference type for const-ness is to remove the reference: `is_const<typename remove_reference<T>::type>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const` is never implicitly discarded, your code for testing whether something "is const" using `std::is_const` is just flawed.
`std::is_const` does not consider the constness of a referred type:

```cpp
std::is_const_v<const int> // true
std::is_const_v<const int&> // false, a const& is not a const type,
                            // it refers to something const
```

Consider what happens in your code:

```cpp
const int ca = 1;
fun(ca); // calls fun<const int&>(ca);

// then:
template <class T> // T = const int&
void fun(T &&b)    // b is declared as const int&
{
    // ...
    std::cout << std::is_const<T>::value << " "; // prints 0, same reason as above
    // ...
```

When bound to lvalues of type `const L`, a forwarding reference `T&&` will deduce `T` to `const L&`. After reference collapsing, `T&&` is just `const L&`.

For your code to give you the expected result, you must use:

```cpp
std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value
// or since C++14
std::is_const<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value
// or since C++17
std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>
```

Answer (score 8):

When `T` is deduced from a forwarding reference with an lvalue argument, then `T` is an lvalue reference type and for any reference type

```
std::is_const<T>::value
```

is always `false`, because reference types can't be `const`-qualified. What you are really interested in is whether the type of the reference is "*lvalue/rvalue-reference to X*" where `X` is some `const`-qualified type, i.e. whether

```
std::is_const<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value
```

is `true`. When we colloquially say that a reference is `const`-qualified, we actually mean this, not that the reference type itself is actually `const`-qualified.